# How to save the return customer data with stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am using payola which is a rails engine for stripe payment. am using the subscriptions method to make subscription. currently users are able to make subscription and can save the data on stripe. how do i save the return data to my database.
on my subscription controller i have it set like this

```
 def create
   # do any required setup here, including finding or creating the owner object
   owner = current_user # this is just an example for Devise

   # set your plan in the params hash
   params[:plan] = SubscriptionPlan.find_by(id: params[:plan_id])

   # call Payola::CreateSubscription
   subscription = Payola::CreateSubscription.call(params, owner)

   # Render the status json that Payola's javascript expects
   render_payola_status(subscription)
   subscriptions = Subscription.new
   subscriptions.stripeid = subscription.id
    subscriptions.customer = subscription.customer
     subscriptions.plan = subscription.plan.name
      subscriptions.subscriptiondate = subscription.current_period_start
       subscriptions.subscriptionenddate = subscription.current_period_end
       subscriptions.save

 end
```

but when i check in my database its empty

Comment: May you show code of ***Subscription*** model?

Comment: `class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end` this the code that i have in my subscription model

Comment: I cannot see where you set user for subscriptions

Comment: this creates a customer on stripe `owner = current_user # this is just an example for Devise

   # set your plan in the params hash
   params[:plan] = SubscriptionPlan.find_by(id: params[:plan_id])

   # call Payola::CreateSubscription
   subscription = Payola::CreateSubscription.call(params, owner)` from there stripe sends back the information. i want to assign that information to a subscription table which belongs to the user

Comment: Change `subscriptions.save` to `subscriptions.save!` and show error messages.

Comment: the subscription create is not rendering.